# Create new column in Python within a group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby, data-science, modeling

I need to create the new variable illustrated as Needed in the snap given below in Spyder. I am getting error. please give the solutions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKEng.png)

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Ankur, please add some code, what you have tried or what you want. So community can help you in right direction. Also image is wrong format of asking question on stack-overflow, please read it here https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Hi Ankit, I am posting the format first time.Will maintain the decorum next time,

Comment: def f(row,i):
    t=i
    for i in t:
        if row['Optin'] == 'Y':
            val='Y'
        elif row['Optin']=='N':
            val='N'
        else:
           val='Both'
        return val,i have used this code not getting the desired result...i was busy in last 2 days,i just saw the msg.

Comment: You can add in post itself, by editing.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
def f(row):
  if (row['id'] == 1):
      return "Both"
  elif (row['id'] == 2):
      return "N"
  elif (row['id'] == 3):
      return "Y"

df["needed"] = df.apply(f,axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, but i have around 1000 id's, so i can't write for each, i have to go with group by in Id's. Please suggest...

Comment: @AnkorSingh you really need to post more information like code or the whole df